# iOS 11 clear navigationbar

Tags: swift, uikit, ios11, xcode9

I've seen various topics on SO for this, but I cannot get any of them to work in iOS 11 with Xcode 9.

I'm trying to make a completely clear navigationBar, but for the life of me I can't get rid of the "frosted" look, nor can I get rid of the bottom etching.

[This is what I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJCn0.png)

And this is my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
    navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = .clear
    navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .clear
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .clear
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: did you try to make it opaque instead of translucent?

Comment: Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40176803/swift-navigation-bar-background-color-white-does-not-work/40178657#40178657

Answer (score 0):

You changed all the properties needed to make it transparent, so the problem is not there. Some things that you could check that might be a problem too:

1. Any type of `UINavigationBar.appearance()` global definition
2. `UINavigationController` and `UINavigationBar` extensions
3. Any other changes that could be made after `viewDidLoad` (`viewWillAppear`, `viewDidAppear`, `layoutSubviews`...) in either the tested classes or its subclasses
4. Customisations on UINavigationController on Storyboard/XIB
5. This is kinda silly but check if your navigationController is not nil

Comment: This is a pretty fresh project, based on Xcode 9's basic master/detail, so most of the things you mentioned haven't been done. The code I posted is, quite literally, the only code in the VC. That being said, I did make a bunch of changes to the storyboard while attempting to get this to work (prior to doing code). I will revert those changes and give ti a whirl.

Comment: added your code to a project with one storyboard with a `UINavigationController` and two `UIViewController` and it worked perfectly. Thats why I suggested different approaches since I don't know the nature of the code you are using. Another thing you could do is to clean, delete derived data and rebuild, since XIBs and storyboards could be cached.

Comment: Good call on the Derived Data.... that very well might be the case. I'll give it a whirl. I'm going to give this another go. Will keep you posted.

Answer (score 0):

So after having created a project using Xcode 9's default Master-Detail template, I determined the problem wasn't DerivedData, but rather the "push into another navigation controller". My project had the following structure:

[What Xcode 9 Generated with Master/Detail template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ic0uJ.png)

I changed it to the following:

[Drop the split view controller & extra navigationcontroller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKKwN.png)

After setting up my storyboard like this it all worked... I was surprised that the using the second navcontroller (the one in which the DetailViewController was embedded) wouldn't work, though. Anybody have any ideas on why?

Answer (score 0):

Try navigationController?.navigationController?.navigationBar

Split view controller puts detail navigation controller into master navigation controller in horizontally compact environment.

So there are two navigation controllers and two navigation bars. You change one navigation bar, but another navigation bar is displayed